# Scraping a website who always has the same URL using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am currently **scraping** a certain website, but the issue is that this website always has the same URL, which is not allowing me to **scrape** it correctly.
I am relatively new to Selenium and I'm currently trying to figure out how I could manage to **scrape** the given site.
The site is : " https://fcraonline.nic.in/fc3_amount.aspx ".
I am looking to **scrape** Each district in each State in each year.
This is the code that I have written so far :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "./chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://fcraonline.nic.in/fc3_amount.aspx")

# find_elements_by_xpath returns an array of selenium objects.
titles_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("adiv[@class=’col-md-12’]")
# use list comprehension to get the actual repo titles and not the selenium objects.
titles = [x.text for x in titles_element]
# print out all the titles.
print('titles:')
print(titles, '\n')
```

If someone could guide me/teach me to solve the issue that would be great.
I thank you all for your time.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 problems here:

1. `adiv[@class=’col-md-12’]` is not a valid XPath expression
2. also there is no elements located by `//div[@class=’col-md-12’]` there
3. After opening a web page you have to set some kind of wait / delay to let the elements loaded and only after that accessing them.

Comment: Yes I have added the following lines that would scroll till the end of the page and wait a few seconds : 
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would use css selectors as they are much more versatile than xpaths. Secondly, if you want to get an element's text, you can just do `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('thecssselector').text` . This will only scrape the text in the element which is what you appear to be trying to do. Hope this helps. Thirdly, I'm unsure of which element you are trying to scrape as - for me - no data is shown other than some selection boxes and a page header and top menu. Make sure you don't need to navigate to get to the right page or perhaps make sure that the element you want has loaded by using Python's in-built time module with `time.sleep(aNumberInSeconds)`.

EDIT: I recommend using Selenium's Expicit/Implicit wait functions for waiting for pages to load, I find normal python time sleeps easier to use when testing single points of failure but for finished code, it's more reliable to use Selenium's. Check out https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load for more info.

Comment: Each box has several elements that we can choose from (District, State, etc.). I am trying to select elements from each box, then click on submit. The submit button would navigate us to another page, which is the page that I am trying to scrape.